# How do I pass an Object to a method that accepts T values?

Tags: java, generics

The method that I need to call, needs `myMethod(final Class<T> clazz, final T value)`.

I have a `java.lang.reflect.Field` and an object and want to make the call like this: `myMethod(field.getType(), value)`

This is where I get into issues...

```
The method myMethod(Class<T>, T) in the type XXX is not applicable for the arguments (Class<capture#8-of ?>, Object)
```

What can I do to make this work ?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your code. How are you invoking the method?

Comment: The method `getTyoe` returns a `Class<?>` and that’s not the type of `value`

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo Yes..my type is Object.. Question remains..what can I do ?

Comment: @GuilhermeMussi it is just a static method...

Comment: @Teshte Isn't it obvious? You can't use `field.getType()` because it tells you nothing about the actual type of `value`. You will have to pass the actual class of `value` to make it work. It seems to me you want to ask for something more, but that’s not obvious to me from your question or it doesn’t reveal enough details to go further than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for the problem was to do the following cast:

```
myMethod((Class<Object>) field.getType(), value)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing (since I don't have the code) that you called it similarly to

```
Object a = ...
myClass.myMethod(a.class, a);
```

But that won't work unless you constructed your `myClass` like so

```
MyClass myClass = new MyClass( ... something that binds T to Object ...);
```

If you have a `myClass` that is bound to a different type, like a more specific type, then `myClass` won't accept `Object` because of the restriction place upon it (either in the writing of `MyClass` or in the compiling of the code instantiating `myClass`.

Comment: the method is called in a static way...and it is defined like this : `public static <T> void setInServiceContext(final Class<T> clazz, final T value) {...}`...The class doesn't know anything about T..

Answer (score 0):

Change your method signature to:

```
<T> void myMethod(final Class<? extends T> clazz, final T value)
```

Calls like this one should now be accepted:

```
public class StackOverflow {

    public BigDecimal myField = BigDecimal.ONE;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {       
        StackOverflow instance = new StackOverflow();
        instance.testCall( instance.getClass().getDeclaredField("myField"), new String ("Demo") );
    }

    public void testCall(Field field, Object value) {                       
        myMethod(field.getType(), value);
    }


    public static <T> void myMethod(final Class<? extends T> clazz, final T value) {
        System.out.println(value);
    }

}
```

Regards,

Bernard.

Comment: Problem is that in `myMethod`, instead of your `System.out.println` I need to call a method with the following signature : `IEclipseContext.set(Class<T> clazz, T value)`...So by doing your suggestion, I would just be moving the problem..and I would be getting the same error when I want to call the set from above

Comment: Cast the 'clazz' before calling:


 public static <T> void myMethod(Class<? extends T> clazz, T value) {     
     setIEclipseContext( (Class<T>) clazz, value);       
    }
    
    public static <T> void setIEclipseContext(Class<T> clazz, T value){   
        System.out.println(value);
    }